# How to check paper size?

Tags: pdftex, paper-size

Is there a way to check what paper size my LaTeX document is set to?

I'm aware I can *set* the paper size using the geometry package, but I want some type of 'check' on this. I don't see anything obvious in the log file.

When I manually check the meta data of the PDF, it gives me the "Resolution" in some type of point system. I can do a bit of math with 72 on it, but I'd rather find some type of "LaTeX-only" way of getting the paper size.

For what it's worth, I am *not* actually using the geometry package in my document. I am not against using it, though, so long as it does not alter the dimensions of my document (which others have reported, even with `pass`).

Comment: I always get this from `pdfinfo` or the document properties in my PDF viewer. The latter gives me mm and, if available, the equivalent standard size e.g. A4 or whatever.

Answer (score 4):

How fancy (and accurate) do you need? If you're not using `geometry`, you could do something like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
%\documentclass{article}
% if you don't load a package like geometry or hyperref (who doesn't use hyperref?), then you could add these two lines
\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
\pdfpageheight=\paperheight


\makeatletter
\newcommand\usemm[1]{%
  \strip@pt\dimexpr0.3514598\dimexpr #1\relax\relax mm%
}
\newcommand\usein[1]{%
  \strip@pt\dimexpr0.013837\dimexpr #1\relax\relax in%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\the\paperheight \par
\the\paperwidth  \par
\the\hsize       \par % or \textwidth
\the\vsize       \par % or \textheight

\usemm{\the\paperheight} \par
\usemm{\the\paperwidth}  \par
\usemm{\the\hsize}       \par
\usemm{\the\vsize}       \par

\usein{\the\paperheight} \par
\usein{\the\paperwidth}  \par
\usein{\the\hsize}       \par
\usein{\the\vsize}       \par
\end{document}
```

Note that there is also this very useful test (for which I always forget the name):

```sh
latex testpage # or: pdflatex testpage
```

which will prompt you about whether you mean to test for `a4paper` or `letterpaper` and whether you want one- or two-sided printing. After the compiling is finished, open the resulting `.dvi` or `.pdf` and see if the hash marks line up to the edge of the page properly. If they do not then you'll need to care about using A4 paper settings or letterpaper documentclass settings in various document classes (unless you load a package that fixes LaTeX's defaul deficiency).

Comment: This won't necessarily match the height and width of the PDF produced, though.

Comment: @cfr -- Hmm, indeed. I'm not used to thinking about page size in a "minimal" document.  Perhaps this edit helps, however.

Comment: Hmm... That's very interesting - never heard of that test. But I'm not quite clear about it. Is there a `testpage` somewhere in the distribution? Or is that the name of your document? But does this really do anything over-and-above telling you to be careful if you live anywhere other than North America?

Comment: Well, of course, it wasn't the command `latex` that I couldn't remember, but the actual file `testpage.tex` (findable in the normal ways when you know the name of the file).  Ad 2: yes: if you've used `tlmgr` to set your default paper size to A4, then you'd have the opposite problem. Anyway, it is (I think) a useful diagnostic if something seems off and you are unaware of the default bug/feature about the native page dimensions.

Comment: @cfr -- Oops, last comment missed you. (Also, this question explains an early, forgotten episode where I was "burned" when preparing a handout for a European conference -- in which I didn't use either geometry or hyperref. Although I thoughtfully added the `a4paper` option to the document class, when I printed the handout, it was off. I had no time and less experience then to figure out what was wrong, but I think I understand now!)

Comment: Definitely agree it is useful to know. I can't upvote again, though ;). I just wasn't clear on the syntax because the code was not initially being displayed correctly - it is much clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `layouts` package which will list all the page layout details including the page height and width. For instance:

```
\documentclass[...]{...}
\usepackage{layouts}
...
\begin{figure}
\centering
\currentpage
\oddpagelayouttrue
\pagedesign
\caption{Odd page layout for this document}
\end{figure}
...
```

will produce a scale diagram of the various aspects of the current page layout together with a list of all the various values (to the nearest pt).