# How to set page size with geometry

Tags: geometry, paper-size

I would like to set page sizes of my project but when I do it the result isn't correct. I read some articles on Google but I didn't understand anything.

This is a head of my project

```
\documentclass[slovak]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[a6paper,top=10mm,bottom=15mm,left=10mm,right=10mm]{geometry} %- my set
```

But when I compile my project pages are A6 but margins aren't correct. But why?

On the picture there is - on the left what I want - on the right what I get.

[image: What I want and what I get.]

It looks correctly but when I try to change margins it hasn't any effect. Margins are set but they haven't my setting. I need a small left margin. I want to use all area of a paper.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: I'm sorry, but completing ans testing you code, I get horizontal margins of `9.8mm` (measured, with option `showframe`). The difference corresponds more or less to the thickness of the frame. So there must be something else.

Comment: A6 is a relatively small paper size, so you need to add showframe to the geometry options, and print the page on a6 paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a6paper,slovak]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}     
\usepackage[top=10mm, bottom=10mm, left=0mm, right=10mm, showframe,
            foot=5mm, marginparsep=0mm]{geometry}

\geometry{bindingoffset=1cm}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
\pdfpageheight=\paperheight


\makeatletter
\newcommand\usemm[1]{%
\strip@pt\dimexpr0.3514598\dimexpr #1\relax\relax mm%
}
\newcommand\usein[1]{%
\strip@pt\dimexpr0.013837\dimexpr #1\relax\relax in%
}
\makeatother

\setlength{\parindent}{0ex}

\begin{document}

\the\paperheight \par
\the\paperwidth  \par
\the\hsize       \par % or \textwidth
\the\vsize       \par % or \textheight

\usemm{\the\paperheight} \par
\usemm{\the\paperwidth}  \par
\usemm{\the\hsize}       \par
\usemm{\the\vsize}       \par

\usein{\the\paperheight} \par
\usein{\the\paperwidth}  \par
\usein{\the\hsize}       \par
\usein{\the\vsize}       \par

\end{document}
```

Everything looks very good and it is correct.

Comment: With `bottom=15mm` it fits your question. Your code is more a less a copy of [@jon s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261312/124842) . I think you should mention that.